# Make emulators automatically sleep/lock after timeout

Tags: lock-screens, android-emulator, sleep

I have tried different emulators on Windows (Leapdroid, Nox MEmu, among others), and none seem to have the ability to automatically timeout on idle and go to the lock screen like almost every device out there. (Manual is not a problem, I'm looking for on idle.)  The screen never goes to sleep, and the screen never locks.  In Android, I have tried:

- Dev mod -> uncheck "stay awake"
- Modifying the sleep settings
- Modifying the lock settings
- Daydream settings

But can't get it to work in any of these emulators.  I have looked for and tried different apps, but also can't get them to do ANYTHING with the screen.  In order of preference:

- time out with actual lock (need to enter the PIN) like a real device
- time out sleep function that at least blanks the screen
- Any sort of independent 'screen saver' workaround which at least blanks the screen somehow
- Any sort of independent 'daydream'-style workaround

But I can't find any app that does any of these or even works when it says it does with android emulators.  Is there any way to have ANY timeout of the current screen state in ANY emulator?

Answer (score 2):

So my solution was to run the emulator (BlueStacks) on a virtual Windows instance on my local app server and then have THAT Windows instance lock.

You don't need an app server, but if you run your app inside a Windows virtual machine, you can have that virtual machine lock.  It has a lot of overhead (but then again so do Android emulators).  You also have to make sure you can enable nested virtualization (virtual machine in a virtual machine).

I did this with KVM in Linux with some tweaks of the CPU settings.